# Passing non constant value(image url) among components in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, image, src, react-props

I have two component classes (**component1**, **component2**) extending Component. 
In component1, I have an image which has an url I need to pass to component2 image source.
I imported **component2** in **component1** by

*Note - These are simplified versions of my files & the passing of a non constant variable is important for my use case*

**Component1.js**

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import component2 from './component2';

    let imageUrl = 'https://someimage-link.com/test.png'

    class Component1 extends Component{

    render(){ 
       return <div>
                <component2 image={imageUrl}/>
              </div>
    }
    export default component1;
```

**Component2.js**

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

    class Component2 extends Component{

    render(){        
      return <div>
               <img src={this.props.image} alt=""/>
             </div>
    }
    export default component2;
```

In **component2** I tried accessing the imageUrl by,

```
    <img src={this.props.image}/>
```

By

```
    console.log({this.props.image});
```

in **component2** I'm able to see the image url which is being passed by **component1** but the img tag is unable to fetch/render it on the page. Is there any other possibility or am I missing something to pass values among components?

Comment: Any error in your console? Or could you provide more code?

Comment: No error in the console. It shows me the correct image url which I passed from component1.

Comment: Could you show us the code for both these components?

Comment: Sure. Plz take a look now.